# Fibonacci Recursion issue, can't return 2 elements

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm having trouble with the code in my else statement. I can't figure out how to make it recursively return the 2 adjusted items in the list. I would appreciate any help.

```
public static int[] fibaux(int n) {

      if (n == 1) {
         return new int[] {1, 0};
      }
      else {
         int[] array = new int[2];
         list[] = {fibaux(n - 1)};


         return //array[0] + array[1], array[1];
      }
 }
```

Comment: `return` returns only one value of type primitive, array, calss, etc..

Comment: you gave the answer already in the question...
Look at your return in `if (n == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Multi-value returns are not allowed in Java i.e., you can not return 2 values using the `return`. You can simply return an `array` containing the two values like this:

```
return new int[] {num1, num2};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for doesn't involve doing the recursion as part of the return.  You want to do the recursion, and then return an array that is the addition of the two elements, along with the one element you want to keep.

I think you want:

```
public static int[] fibaux(int n) {
      if (n == 1) {
         return new int[] {1, 0};
      }
      else {
         int[] array = fibaux(n - 1);
         return new int[] {array[0]+array[1], array[0]};
      }
}
```